# How to print only image on my web page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-applications

I have a web page which creates Barcodes. I want to print this Barcode to the sticker. That is why I want to print only selected area(only barcode) and I don't want to print header and footer of the webpage.Only barcode.

How can I do this problem?

Thank your for your attention!!!

P.S The web page is created on ASP.NET with C#

Comment: How would you print a web page? Is custom `Print` link which navigates to an other pae is appropriate solution for you?

Answer (score 8):

First, create a print version of your CSS document which hides the header and footer.

```
/* print.css */
#header { display: none; }
#footer { display: none; }
```

Next, link the stylesheet in the head of your HTML document as the "print" stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

After making these changes, the header and footer will not be included in print output.

Answer (score 2):

I would use CSS's `@media print` to handle this:

```
@media print
{
    /* Add this to everything that you don't want to print (your header and footer) */
    .noPrint
    {
        display:none;
    }

    /* You could also reference your header and footer containers specifically */
    #headerContainer
    {
        display:none;
    }

    #footerContainer
    {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

If you want to keep your print CSS seperated in another file, add the `media="print"` attribute to your `link` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printCSS.css" media="print">
```

**Note:** If you're simply defining a `noPrint` CSS class, I see no reason to create a whole new CSS file to house that simply class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a custom css class for printing.  Just specify the media attribute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Check out [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/03/13/CSSBasedPrintingTip.aspx) tutorial.